# How to change different border colors of multiple angular material checkboxes nested in mat-menu and mat-toolbar?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I have 3  material check boxes inside mat-menu that is inside mat-toolbar.
I need each check box border different color.

```
<mat-menu #m1="matMenu" class="mat-menu-panel-custom">

  <mat-toolbar>
              <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
              <mat-checkbox class="a02"></mat-checkbox>
              <mat-checkbox class="a03"></mat-checkbox>
  </mat-toolbar>
  
 </mat-menu>
```

This changes color for all:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-frame {
    border-color: white
}
```

but I do not seem to find a way to change color for individual check boxes.
I tried:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox.a02 {
  border-color: yellow !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox.a03 {
  border-color: orange !important;
}
```

and

```
    .menu-panel .mat-checkbox.a02 {
      border-color: yellow;
    }

    .menu-panel .mat-checkbox.a03 {
      border-color: white;
    }
```

etc. but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This seams to work

```
    .a02 ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-frame {
      border-color: yellow;
    }

    .a03 ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-frame {
      border-color: orange;
    }
```